# search for string in text file in vb and print lines

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Hi I am new to VB and just though if someone could help me in my current scenario

I have a text file named shar.txt
It has 6 lines in it.

I am a new student
I am learning VB
Please help me friends
Friends always matter in our life
Thank You for your support
Always grateful to you

I want a script which reads this text file and look for the string such as "Friends", "support" and print the lines containing those strings in another text file at the same location say "sha.txt"

I tried till this point but lost my way i mid.

Please someone help me.
thanks

```
Sub ReadToTextFile()
Dim strPattern1 As String    
Dim strPattern2 As String    
H1 As String    
H2 As String    
strPattern1 = "friends"    
strPattern2 = "support"    


Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\Users\sonu\Desktop\auto\shar.txt", 1, True)    
Do Until
 objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream        
    strLine = objFileToRead.ReadLine        
    ElseIf 
InStr(strLine, strPattern1) > 0    
 Then        
        Wscript.Echo strLine    
                H1 = strLine    
                ElseIf 
InStr(strLine, strPattern2) > 0        
 Then        
                Wscript.Echo strLine    
                H2 = strLine    
           End If    

    End If    
Loop    

Wscript.Echo H2    

Set objFileToRead = Nothing    

End Sub
```

Comment: My code looks like this

Comment: Sorry unable to paste my code here due to word limitations.

Comment: edit your question and paste your code there. Remember to format it appropriately using `{}` icon.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? I mean really? With code?

Comment: Hi please help me in modifying the above code or the code given by Panayot as that code looks fine but it's giving error as Run Time mismatch error:13

Comment: Thanks Mike for formating the code.Can u pls help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very bad formed question for this site. It's good for you to spend some time to read the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Anyway, this is from me.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Dim FSO, FileIn, FileOut, strTmp

Set FSO     = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FileIn  = FSO.OpenTextFile("shar.txt", ForReading)
Set FileOut = FSO.OpenTextFile("sha.txt", ForWriting, True)

Do Until FileIn.AtEndOfStream
    strTmp = FileIn.ReadLine
    If Len(strTmp) > 0 Then
        If InStr(1, strTmp, "Friends", vbTextCompare) > 0 _
        Or InStr(1, strTmp, "support", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            FileOut.WriteLine strTmp
        End If
    End If
Loop

FileIn.Close
FileOut.Close
```

EDIT: About your question for using arrays...

```
' an example array
arWords = Array("friends", "support", "xyz")
' modified Do..Loop
Do Until FileIn.AtEndOfStream
    strTmp = FileIn.ReadLine
    If Len(strTmp) > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(arWords)
            If InStr(1, strTmp, arWords(i), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                FileOut.WriteLine strTmp
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
Loop
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Panayot,thank you for the help.When I run the above code it gives me error as Run Time mismatch error:13.Please advise

Comment: @user2516021 Oh, sorry, my bad, thanks for report. I was swap first and second arguments in `InStr` function, now it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks Panayot,It worked.. :)can you please advise how can I implement the same logic with arrays as variable for storing the strings and printing later on....Please advise if I am not clear in my Question..Thanks In advance...!!!

Comment: Hi Panayot,just 1 more question,is it possible that I can print the lines in an outlook email,instead of Text file...Please help me once more friend..!! Thank You..!!

Comment: @user2516021 I can't help on this task as I not using Outlook, but post this as new topic and am sure someone will helps.

Comment: No Problem Panayot,I will post this as a new question,thanks for your help