# Return Row Value from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I need to return a value by searching for a string in 3-4 Excel files. The value should be the data of the row that matches my searchstring.

How it works:

1. UserForm has a TextBox to enter a string
2. UserForm has a Button that should take the string onPress and check the Excel files for the string
3. If the string is found then get the values in that row
4. If I have the values, save those in the Excel file I call this macro from

I tried two ways:

First approach

```vb
Sub ReadDataFromAnotherWorkBook()

    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
    Dim FirstFound As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    ' Open Workbook A with specific location
    Dim src As Workbook
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\test\xx304..xlsx", True, True)      
    
    ' Set Search value
    SearchString = TextBox1.Value        ' TEST with TextBox Value -- works
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    ' loop through all sheets
    For Each sh In src.Worksheets
        ' Find first instance on sheet
        Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(what:=SearchString, _
            After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            ' if found, remember location
            FirstFound = cl.Address
            MsgBox FirstFound
            ' format found cell
            Do
                '  cl.Font.Bold = True
                '  cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Debug.Print FirstFound
                MsgBox FirstFound         ' does not work
              
'              Debug.Print cl.Value
'              MsgBox cl.Value            ' I expected the value here
                ' find next instance
                Set cl = sh.Cells.FindNext(After:=cl)
                ' repeat until back where we started
            Loop Until FirstFound = cl.Address
        End If
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Value im Excel? : " + FirstFound   'cl.Value        > the return is empty 

    MsgBox "SEARCHSTRING :: " + SearchString   ' works - I have the searchstring I need

    ' Close Workbooks A                        ' closes the wb
    src.Close False
    Set src = Nothing

End Sub
```

My second approach was something like this:

```vb
Sub ReadDataFromAnotherWorkBookTEST2()       ' 2nd approach

' Open Workbook A with specific location
Dim src As Workbook
Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\x\Desktop\x\test\x304..xlsx", True, True)
    
Dim oFound As Range
Dim oLookin As Range

Dim test As Worksheet

Dim sLookFor As String

sLookFor = TextBox1.Value                 ' TextBoxValue

MsgBox "SearchString " + sLookFor         ' works got the right string 

Set oLookin = src.Worksheets("Tabelle1").UsedRange       

' Set test = src.Worksheets("Tabelle1")     ' Find geht nicht auf WorkSheet

Set oFound = oLookin.Find(what:=sLookFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

Dim oAdjacent As Range

If Not oFound Is Nothing Then
     Debug.Print "Found? : " & oFound.Address
     MsgBox "this Box does not spawn..  " + oLookin.Range("A" & oFound.Row).Value
 '   ActiveCell.Value = oLookin.Range("A" & oFound.Row).Value
 '   Set oAdjacent = oFound.Offset(0, 1) ' One cell to right
    
End If

' Close Workbooks A                                 ' Closes the Workbook
src.Close False
Set src = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: How does `Msgbox FirstFound` not work?  If your `Find` statement finds something it will give the same message for each loop as it's the first found address.  If you want it to display the other addresses use `Msgbox cl.Address`.

Comment: On a side note it's generally better to use `&` rather than `+` when concatenating strings: `1 & 1 = 11` while `1 + 1 = 2`.

Comment: Let's say your string is found in cell `J10`. What will you use to write from and where to? For example, use the value in column `A` and write to column `A` in worksheet "Sheet1" of calling workbook, or copy the entire row to the next available row in "Sheet1"... Where will you write to, if there are more occurrences of your string?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook the MessageBox is not getting called so I feel like there is a logicalerror in the loop or taking the worksheet properly

Comment: @VBasic2008 I am calling this macro in an Excel File. In that Excel the user defines the searchstring. The Macro then searches another Excel FIle looking if that string is there and if it is I want to get the Value that is basically next to it in the row. If I have that Value I then want to write something depending on that value in the sheet where the macro gets called from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Find Multiple Occurrences of a String in Multiple Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReadDataFromAnotherWorkBook()

    Dim swb As Workbook
    Set swb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\test\xx304..xlsx", True, True)
    Debug.Print "Processing workbook '" & swb.Name & "'..."
    
    Dim sString As String: sString = TextBox1.Value
    Debug.Print "Searching for '" & sString & "'..."
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim fAddress As String
    
    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        Debug.Print "Processing worksheet '" & sws.Name & "'..."
        Set srg = sws.UsedRange
        Set sCell = srg.Find(What:=sString, _
            After:=srg.Cells(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
        If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
            fAddress = sCell.Address
            Do
                Debug.Print "Found string in '" & sCell.Address(0, 0) _
                    & "'. The value in " & sCell.Offset(, 1).Address(0, 0) _
                    & " is " & sCell.Offset(, 1).Value
                Set sCell = srg.FindNext(sCell)
            Loop Until sCell.Address = fAddress
        End If
    Next
    swb.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks dude! I actually get the right Value if the string is found. There is still much to do but at least you've helped me to the next step. Ty

Comment: is there a possibility to change the activeCell value where this gets called from? I tried to add an If-Statement after the Loop before the Next - If (sCell.Offset(, 1).Value = "vorhanden") Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(, 14).Value = 2                   
            End If 
__ this does not work I feel like I am selecting the wrong activecell or something

Comment: If I am Debug.Printing the ActiveCell.Address I am always getting H29 for some Reason even though the Funtion gets called from a UserForm that should have the right ActiveCell beacuse it should always get called from another Cell. Double Click on ActiveCell opens userform and the button inside that userform executes "your" Function. How can I get the ActiveCell on that the UserForm was called on..

Comment: `ActiveCell` is something that is most often avoided, as is any flavor of `Active` (and `Select`). You should ask another question including this code if it works, and the new requirements (the part that you're modifying). Maybe add some screenshots. You could post a link to the new question in the comments of this question so contributors who were (are) interested could easily find it.

Comment: yeah I already posted a new Question and got help for now - Thanks again